# Identify "tab" in background script as your own "newtab" page without "tabs" permission

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The extension I've built has both the background script and overrides the "newtab" page.
Can I, without "tabs" or "all_urls" permission, know in the background script "chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener" that my own newtab page has been opened? With "tabs" permission, I simply check the URL.

My ultimate goal is to take the focus from Omnibox and put it in my own input search on the newtab page. I have that working well now and the thing that I want to do is remove "tabs" permission because it tells users that I'm reading their browsing history. And it's just scary.  Opt-in and optional permission "tabs" is something that I want to avoid because the "default" behavior is always the king, and has the highest usage.

What I've tried:

- "chrome-extension//*", "chrome-extension", "chrome-extension///*" in manifest.json permissions. It always results in an error like this "Permission 'chrome-extension//' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed".
- Script in  of the newtab.html page with window.chrome.runtime.sendMessage to inform the background script it's a new tab that was opened. It's not fast enough. chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener fires much faster.
- Meta tag with redirect to the newtab.html hosted somewhere online. Works nice, but this feature has to be an opt-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **ManifestV2**: use [chrome.extension.getViews](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews)

  background.js:

  ```js
  chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(tab => {
    const onUpdated = (tabId, info, updatedTab) => {
      if (tabId === tab.id && info.status && chrome.extension.getViews({tabId})[0]) {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated);
        console.log('My newtab', updatedTab);
        // doSomething(tab);
      }
    };
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onUpdated);
  });
  ```
- **ManifestV3**: use `fetch` event:

  background.js:

  ```js
  let isOpeningMyTab;

  self.onfetch = e => {
    // assuming your page is chrome-extension://**id**/newtab.html
    if (e.request.url.startsWith(location.origin + '/newtab.html')) {
      isOpeningMyTab = true;
      setTimeout(() => { isOpeningMyTab = false; });
    }
  };

  chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(tab => {
    if (isOpeningMyTab) {
      console.log('My newtab', tab);
      // doSomething(tab);
    }
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Just the small thing, the first script does not work. In "onCreated" it's not yet recognized, but if I change it to this, then it works.
```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'loading') {
    const [view] = chrome.extension.getViews({ type: 'tab', tabId });
    if (view) {
      console.log('My newtab', tab);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Indeed, the tab's contents hasn't yet started to load in onCreated.